# Opening a subset of bookmarks in a Bookmark Folder

Tags: safari

I imported my bookmark folders from Chrome, which I now hate.  How can I open a *subset* of bookmarks in a folder, but NOT ALL bookmarks in the folder, each in a NEW tab.  I am using Safari 7.1.5 and OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 1):

Which ever way you look through the Bookmarks in Safari, it will offer you the option a sub menu to "open In Tabs"

Example: From the Bookmarks menu bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Break your tabs down into smaller sets using the Bookmarks sidebar.

You can add folders, move content etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible with Safari. Even opening the Bookmark Editor, where you can select multiple bookmarks at once, gets rid of your selection when you right-click and only chooses the bookmark under your cursor to interact with.

You would need to sort your bookmarks manually into the chunks of tabs that you want to open, each in its own folder.